# Spark-sklearn GridSearch integration code failed when run in Spark yarn mode

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I copied the spark-sklearn GridSearch example from http://go.databricks.com/hubfs/notebooks/Samples/Miscellaneous/blog_post_cv.html and used the spark-sklearn python package to run the GridSearch in a distributed environment using spark. My version of python is 2.7, spark 2.1.0

I run it in spark using --master local  `spark-submit --master local XGBoostGridSearch.py`. The code ran successfully.

When I ran the same code in spark using --master yarn `spark-submit --master yarn --py-files spark_sklearn.zip TestGridSearch.py`, the code failed with the following error message

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):

return pickle.loads(obj)

ImportError: No module named sklearn.ensemble.forest
```

The module sklearn.ensemble.forest and all other python dependencies are already installed on all executors via Anaconda2 but still getting the above error message. Following is my code

```
from sklearn import grid_search, datasets
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
digits = datasets.load_digits()
X, y = digits.data, digits.target
param_grid = {"max_depth": [3, None],
              "max_features": [1, 3, 10],
              "min_samples_split": [1, 3, 10],
              "min_samples_leaf": [1, 3, 10],
              "bootstrap": [True, False],
              "criterion": ["gini", "entropy"],
              "n_estimators": [10, 20, 40, 80]}
#gs = grid_search.GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(), param_grid=param_grid)
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SciKitLearn-GridSearch")\
    .config("spark.network.timeout","10000s")\
    .config("spark.rpc.askTimeout","10000s").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("spark_sklearn.zip")
from spark_sklearn import GridSearchCV
gs = GridSearchCV(spark.sparkContext, RandomForestClassifier(), param_grid)
gs.fit(X, y)
```

Note: TestGridSearch.py is where my code resides.

Baffled to see it runs in spark local mode but not in yarn (Distributed) mode. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you believe that dependencies are present then Spark is most likely not using interpreter you believe it does. Double check the path and `PYSPARK_PYTHON` for the worker nodes.

Comment: Thanks @zero323. You are correct. Spark worker noders were not pointing to correct python location. I set the python location for all spark worker nodes using `spark.pyspark.python            /mnt/opt/anaconda/bin/python`  in spark-defaults.conf file.  It started working.